# Android Collapsable Notification Extra padding

Tags: android

When the notification is collapsed with no content, there is an extra padding. This goes crazy on some devices! Samsung galaxy S7 shows a HUGE gap.

My question is: How do I make the highlighted notification to be shown exactly as the ones below it (without the gap, and with the "subtitle" if possible)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to set [`IMPORTANCE_NONE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#IMPORTANCE_NONE) as your notification channel importance through [`setImportance`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel.html#setImportance(int)) method.